# How to implement a fully generic Visitor for a hierarchy of classes in C++1x?

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, metaprogramming, visitor-pattern

I'd like to implement a fully generic Visitor pattern using >= C++14 using template metaprogramming. I've already found a nice way to generalize the Visitor itself, but I'm having trouble defining the Visitables. The code below works, but I'd like the commented out code in `main` to work as well; in particular, I want to be able to have a collection of Visitables and apply a Visitor to each element.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in C++?

Things I've tried:

- `class X : public Visitable<X>`
  This solves the problem of not having a suitable `accept` method in
  `X`, but results in ambiguities `X/A` and `X/B` which the compiler 
  cannot resolve.
- empty `accept` method in `X` without inheriting; works, but the 
  specialized `accept` methods in `A` and `B` are never called.
- replace template class `Visitor` with regular class with function 
  template `visit` for arbitrary types; does not really change the 
  semantics, but is less readable IMHO

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename I>
class Visitable {
 public:
  template <typename Visitor>
  void accept(Visitor&& v) const {
    v.visit(static_cast<const I&>(*this));
  }
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class Visitor : public Visitor<Ts...> {
 public:
  virtual void visit(const T& t);
};

template<typename T>
class Visitor<T> {
 public:
  virtual void visit(const T& t);
};

struct X {
  // template <typename V> void accept(V&& v) const {};
};

struct A : public X, public Visitable<A> {};
struct B : public X, public Visitable<B> {};

class MyVisitor : public Visitor<A, B> {
 public:
  void visit(const A& a) override { std::cout << "Visiting A" << std::endl; }
  void visit(const B& b) override { std::cout << "Visiting B" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  MyVisitor v {};
  // std::vector<X> elems { A(), B() };
  // for (const auto& x : elems) {
  //  x.accept(v);
  // }
  A().accept(v);
  B().accept(v);
}
```

Comment: Just a piece of food for thought: When going full blown templates is it useful to stick to the principles of the strictly runtime polymorphic Gang-of-Four-style Visitor implementation? Templates are sufficiently different that those principles might not help, but stand in the way. Maybe instead take a long hard look at what the actual *pattern* tries to achieve.

Comment: Mmh, that‘s a really interesting idea - maybe double dispatch (which is what I‘m trying to do) could be done differently? I‘ll think about that. Scala has these superneat ˋcase classˋes, which you can iterate over automatically in a type-safe way. That would be cool to have, but I‘m not sure if it‘s possible to emulate that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your current solution:

1. You don't have a polymorphic type that can represent any visitable type. This means that you don't have a way to properly store all your `A` and `B` values in a collection such that you can visit every element in the collection. `X` doesn't accomplish this because there is no way to require that a subclass of `X` also subclasses an instantiation of the `Visitable` class template.
2. You have no way of handling a mismatch of visitor/visitable types; you cannot guarantee that all values in your collection are visitable by some visitor type, without simply making the collection a `vector<A>` or `vector<B>`, in which case you lose the ability to store values of different visitable types in the same collection. You either need a way to handle *at runtime* the scenario of a visitor/visitable mismatch, or you need a much more complex template structure.
3. You cannot store polymorphic values directly in a collection. This is because `vector` stores its elements consecutively in memory, and therefore must assume a certain constant size for each element; by their nature polymorphic values have an unknown size. The solution is to use a collection of (smart) pointers to refer to polymorphic values elsewhere on the heap.

Here's a working adaptation of your original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Visitor;

class VisitorBase {
public:
    virtual ~VisitorBase() {}
};

class VisitableBase {
public:
    virtual void accept(VisitorBase& v) const = 0;
    virtual ~VisitableBase() {}
};

template <typename I>
class Visitable : public VisitableBase {
public:
    virtual void accept(VisitorBase& v) const {
        auto visitor = dynamic_cast<Visitor<I> *>(&v);
        if (visitor == nullptr) {
            // TODO: handle invalid visitor type here
        } else {
            visitor->visit(dynamic_cast<const I &>(*this));
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Visitor : public virtual VisitorBase {
public:
    virtual void visit(const T& t) = 0;
};

struct A : public Visitable<A> {};
struct B : public Visitable<B> {};

class MyVisitor : public Visitor<A>, public Visitor<B> {
public:
    void visit(const A& a) override { std::cout << "Visiting A" << std::endl; }
    void visit(const B& b) override { std::cout << "Visiting B" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    MyVisitor v {};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<VisitableBase>> elems {
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<VisitableBase>(std::make_shared<A>()),
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<VisitableBase>(std::make_shared<B>())
    };
    for (const auto& x : elems) {
        x->accept(v);
    }
    A().accept(v);
    B().accept(v);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! What’s interesting though is that ˋstd::vector<X> vs { A(), B() };ˋ works - I wonder what’s happening under the hood? Are the objects sliced to ˋXˋ? That would mean there is no way of getting the original classes back?

Comment: About your solution: I‘d really like to avoid the ˋdynamic_castˋs. E.g., the linting tools at my company would immediately flag that as a code smell. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
struct empty_t{};
template <class I, class B=empty_t>
class Visitable:public B {
public:

// ...

struct X : Visitable<X>{
};

struct A : Visitable<A,X> {};
struct B : Visitable<B,X> {};
```

Note however that dispatch here is static.  And your vector contains `X`s not `A`s or `B`s.

You probably want

```
template <class Visitor>
struct IVisitable {
  virtual void accept(Visitor const& v) const = 0;
protected:
  ~IVisitable(){}
};

template <class I, class Visitor, class B=IVisitable<Visitor>>
struct Visitable {
  virtual void accept(Visitor const& v) const override {
    v.visit(static_cast<const I&>(*this));
  }
};
```

which gets closer.

```
struct A; struct B; struct X;
struct X:Visitable<X, Visitor<A,B,X>> {
};

struct A :Visitable<A, Visitor<A,B,X>, X> {};
struct B :Visitable<B, Visitor<A,B,X>, X> {};
```

this still doesn't do what you want, because you have a vector of values.  And polymorphic values require more work.

Make it a vector of unique ptrs to X, and add `virtual ~X(){}` and some `*` and `make_unique`s and this will do what you want.

Comment: I will play around with that idea, I think the general approach with inheriting from the template parameter class may be the right way to go. Gets unwieldy, though. Doubt that I‘ll be able to understand that stuff in a few weeks time, much less explain it.